# Algorithm to match groups of unique pairs until all pairs have gone for even and odd pairs

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am working on a problem where I have an array and need to match pairs each week until all pairs have gone together in Swift. It should work for an infinite number of items in the array, so an array of 3 would result in 3 pairs with 1 alone, an array of 5 would create 10 results with 2 pairs and 1 alone, and so on and so forth. Elsewhere this is called a [round robin tournament](https://www.devenezia.com/javascript/article.php/RoundRobin2.html) and my goal is to have it work for even and odd inputs.

Example:

```
var array = ["Tom", "Bob", "Bill"]
```

Expected result (does not necessarily need to be in this exact format as long as there is 1 line per "week" or "group"):

```
["Tom & Bob, Bill", "Tom & Bill, Bob", "Bill & Bob, Tom"]
```

I've written an algorithm to chunk this into sets of 2:

```
func chunks(by size: Int) -> [[String]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: self.count, by: size).map {
            Array(self[$0..<Swift.min($0 + size, self.count)])
        }
    }
```

But I am not sure how to go about doing the first part of getting all possible combinations. I know the equation of `numberOfItems * (numberOfItems - 1) / 2` will give me the number of possible combinations. I also know that each time I create a new pair, I need to check that it does not an item already in the new array.

From there, I assume I need to iterate over the combinations and use the above func to split each set into groups, but am not totally sure how to do that while ensuring they are unique. I've currently got the chunks inside an array extension and assume that the entire thing can be put into an extension to apply to my array. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe start with this https://dev.to/rrampage/algorithms-generating-combinations-100daysofcode-4o0a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, it's certainly not pretty, but here is the class for my solution:

```
class Combinations {
    func possibleCombinations(array: [String]) -> [String] {
        var schedule : [String] = []
        var group = array
        let single = ""
        if group.count % 2 != 0 {
            group.insert(single, at: 0)
        }
        var numRounds = 0
        while numRounds < group.count - 1 {
            for i in 0 ..< group.count / 2 {
                let person1 = group[i]
                let person2 = group[group.count - i - 1]
                if person1 != "" && person2 != "" {
                    let pair = "\(person1) & \(person2)"
                    schedule.append(pair)
                } else if person1 != "" {
                    schedule.append(single)
                } else if person2 != "" {
                    let single = "\(person2)"
                    schedule.append(single)
                }
            }
            var newRound = [group[0], group[group.count - 1]]
            for i in 1 ..< group.count - 1 {
                newRound.append(group[i])
            }
            group = newRound
            numRounds += 1
        }
    let chunkSize = Int((Double(schedule.count) / Double(array.count)).rounded())
    let formattedSchedule = stride(from: 0, to: schedule.count, by: chunkSize).map { schedule[$0..<min($0 + chunkSize, schedule.count)].joined(separator: ", ") }
    schedule = formattedSchedule
    return schedule
    }
}
```